# hover, z-index and layering... a convoluted mess?

Tags: html, css

I'm a web developer noob and hoping someone with more experience can help.

```html
<div id="domain-background-container">
  <div class="domain-hotspots">
    <div id="hotspot">
      <p class="bubble">I'm red on hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-nav" >
  <p>I'm red on hover</p>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {      /* <--- (1) */
  height: 100%; }

#domain-background-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10; }  /* <--- (2) */

.domain-hotspots {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed; 
  background: blue; }

  #hotspot {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: green; }

  #hotspot:hover .bubble {
    background: red; }

#page-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow; }

#page-nav:hover p {
  color: red; }
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc8sptv9/1/).

The problem is that #hotspot (that is the green square) doesn't enter the hover state when the mouse cursor is placed over it.

I'm looking to have four things explained:

1. Can someone provide or point me to a detailed explanation of the mechanics preventing #hotspot from entering the hover state?
2. Removing CSS ruleset (1) [height: 100% for html and body] allows #hotspot to enter the hover state. This isn't a viable solution in my project, but for curiosity's stake, why does this make a difference.
3. Removing the the z-index of CSS ruleset (2) also allows #hotspot to enter the hover state. Unfortunately, this also screws up z-ordering as .domain-hotspots (blue) then covers #page-nav (yellow) which isn't acceptable. Theoretically I could position and raise the z-value of #page-nav. While that would work for this simple jsfiddle I'm loath to do that for a bigger project where I'd have to apply that to every element following .domain-hotspots (which shouldn't even be necessary, because to my understanding elements with unmodified z-index  which follow .domain-hotspots in the html file should be rendered on top of .domain-hotspots in the viewport) :-/
4. I can't use the two "solutions" I just mentioned, so what solution remains?

I'd really appreciate any knowledge people can share on this! I'm stumped. I'm not even sure what I should google for to research the issue, as I don't know what's causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone provide or point me to a detailed explanation of the mechanics preventing `#hotspot` from entering the hover state?

`<body>` is covering it up.
This can be seen by using the "Inspect element" function of a browser's dev tools.
(Due to the way `z-index` works though, giving it a `background` does not put that background in front of the div.)

> Removing CSS ruleset (1) [height: 100% for html and body] allows `#hotspot` to enter the hover state. This isn't a viable solution in my project, but for curiosity's stake, why does this make a difference.

With `height: 100%`:

[image: screenshot]

Without `height: 100%`:

[image: screenshot]

> [...] to my understanding elements with unmodified z-index which follow .domain-hotspots in the html file should be rendered on top of `.domain-hotspots` in the viewport.

From the [CSS Level 2 draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index), § 9.9.1:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

- `#page-nav` is category 3 due to the default `display: block` on any `<div>`.
- `#domain-background-container` is category 2 due to `position: fixed`, which removes it from the flow and creates a child stacking context, and due to its negative `z-index`.

Category 3 gets rendered over category 2, so `#page-nav` is in front of `#domain-background-container`.
Now when you remove the `z-index` from `#domain-background-container`, or make it 0 or positive, it becomes category 6 or 7, thus being rendered after (i.e. over) `#page-nav`.

> Theoretically I could position and raise the z-value of #page-nav. While that would work for this simple jsfiddle I'm loath to do that for a bigger project where I'd have to apply that to every element following .domain-hotspots. [...] I can't use the two "solutions" I just mentioned, so what solution remains?

You don't actually have to raise its `z-value`, you merely have to position it. `position: relative` will do, even.
And applying that to every element following `#domain-background-container` is no miracle either:

```css
#domain-background-container ~ * {
    position: relative;
}
```

Works quite well:

```css
html, body {      /* <--- (1) */
  height: 100%; }

#domain-background-container {
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: -10;*/ }  /* <--- (2) */

#domain-background-container ~ * {
  position: relative; }

.domain-hotspots {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed; 
  background: blue; }

  #hotspot {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: green; }

  #hotspot:hover .bubble {
    background: red; }

#page-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow; }

#page-nav:hover p {
  color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="domain-background-container">
  <div class="domain-hotspots">
    <div id="hotspot">
      <p class="bubble">I'm red on hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-nav" >
  <p>I'm red on hover</p>
</div>
```

Admittedly though, there are situations where it is not feasible to position all those elements.

Another solution though, is to simply position the `body` element, which then allows you to give it a `z-index` of its own:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -11;
}
```

Demo:

```css
html, body {      /* <--- (1) */
  height: 100%; }

body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -11; }

#domain-background-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10; }  /* <--- (2) */

#domain-background-container ~ * {
  position: relative; }

.domain-hotspots {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed; 
  background: blue; }

  #hotspot {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: green; }

  #hotspot:hover .bubble {
    background: red; }

#page-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow; }

#page-nav:hover p {
  color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="domain-background-container">
  <div class="domain-hotspots">
    <div id="hotspot">
      <p class="bubble">I'm red on hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-nav" >
  <p>I'm red on hover</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great explanation :) got a vote from me (even though I had my answer first here ;) )

Comment: Awsome answer! Managed to answer all my questions including those I didn't know I wanted answered. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

1. By setting the `#domain-background-container` to `z-index: -10`, you actually put that div behind the `body` tag, so you hover on the `body` tag and not on the `#hotspot` tag.
2. By removing the 100% height on the `body` & `html` elements, the `body` element's height will actually be height of the `#page-nav` element (because the other element is positioned as `fixed`, so it will not take height of the page) - hence - you can hover it, because there is no other element that sits "before" it - z-index based.
3. Not sure if there is a question here (?)
4. You solution can be to set the position of `#nav-page` to `relative` and remove the `z-index` on the `#domain-background-container`.

Here is an example:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}

#domain-background-container {
  position: fixed;
}

.domain-hotspots {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed; 
  background: blue; 
}

#hotspot {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: green; 
}

#hotspot:hover .bubble {
  background: red; 
}

#page-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow; 
  position: relative;
}

#page-nav:hover p {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
  <div id="domain-background-container">
    <div class="domain-hotspots">
      <div id="hotspot">
        <p class="bubble">I'm red on hover</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="page-nav" >
    <p>I'm red on hover</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's amazing how just a little more information can transform a "nonsensical mess" into something that makes complete sense! Thank you so much! Apparently stackexchange forces me to choose but one post as "the answer", so I had to give that to Siguza since he amazingly managed to clear up #3 for me, where I wasn't even able to state my question in a coherent manner. Still, thank you and everyone else below for the great and very quick answers. Very much appreciated! I'm gaining a new level of respect for web developers ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The rules governing how this all works is a bit complex; if you really want to look into it, see [Appendix E. Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) from the CSS spec. As to your specific questions:

1. The hotspot is not triggered because `#domain-background-container` is at a negative `z-index`, so the body, which has the default `z-index`, covers it and "blocks" the pointer events. You can see this in action if you go into the developer tools and use the "click to select an element" feature; the body is highlighted instead of the hotspot because it's on top.
2. If you remove the height of the body, because the body only contains positioned elements, the body's natural height is now 0, so it no-longer blocks the background. An element only has height if you give it one or if it contains "flowing" elements (not absolute or fixed) that lend it height.
3. Yes, playing the z-index game does not scale well in a project; keep it to a minimum and try to use natural stacking whenever possible.
4. It's not clear what your intention is with your page's layout, but there are multiple potential solutions. You can use `pointer-events: none` on elements where you want the mouse events to "pass through" to a lower level, for example.

Sample:

```
body {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#domain-background-container {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Dito Dekel! Also valuable to understand that approach! Thank you!